# How does aws-sdk in Lambda get the credentials automagically?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-iam

If you use aws-sdk in a Lambda runtime, you don't need provide the credentials to the SDK because it gets the credentials automatically from the execution role of that Lambda function.

I'm curious about that how does this work under the hood? Does the SDK read the credentials from some env variables? How does it get the credentials from the Lambda runtime actually?

Answer (score 14):

> Does the SDK read the credentials from some env variables?

Yes. They are taken from [Runtime environment variables](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/configuration-envvars.html#configuration-envvars-runtime) which include:

- AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID
- AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY
- AWS_SESSION_TOKEN

which come from:

> The access keys obtained from the **function's execution role**.

Answer (score 1):

Parallely also check if you are using
these keywords as key names in your env

```
AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID
AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY
AWS_REGION
```

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/configuration-envvars.html#configuration-envvars-runtime

these are reserved key names, so use other names instead.

In my case this was the issue.
Inside AWS Lambda you can also add your environment variables which your function/application can access
[image]